# How to remove a large amount of Component elements from WiX source code?

Tags: xslt, wix

Now I have a text file in which full paths(source) of files I want to remove from WiX source code are listed. How can I remove all Component elements that contain the files listed in the text file(maybe using xslt)? In addition, all component elements are being referenced from corresponding ComponentReg elements. So, I should remove that references too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input XML?

Comment: Would you be using xslt 1.0 or 2.0?